# Is it possible to use Prisma in a react native app?

Tags: react-native, prisma

In order to quickly prototype ideas for a personal project I'm interested in a solution where I use Prisma directly from a react native app. (I'm aware this is not something you'd do in production.) Data for the single user app would be stored in some free SQL cloud DB.   I would store auth information locally in the client.
Is this possible just like it would be possible in a nodejs Cli or webapp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently Prisma only works on servers so you would need to use it on Node. There's a request for [react-native support](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5011) so you can add upvote the request.

Comment: Upvoted before! I don't see anything that would make Prisma dependent on node other than the way it scans `.env`. I hope they give it priority.